# Flutter: use named routes with custom page route builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project at the moment I am navigating between screens like this:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   CustomPageRouteBuilder().getPageRouteBuilder(MainPage()),
);
```

The `CustomPageRouteBuilder`:

```
class CustomPageRouteBuilder {
  getPageRouteBuilder(Widget widget) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
        transitionDuration: Duration(
          milliseconds: 500,
        ),
        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secAnimation, Widget child) {
          animation = CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.elasticInOut,
          );
          return ScaleTransition(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            scale: animation,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secAnimation) {
          return LayoutPage(widget);
        });
  }
}
```

How could I use named routes + this `CustomPageRouteBuilder`?

If I have these:

```
class Routes {
  static const String loginPage = "/loginPage";
  static const String mainPage = "/mainPage";
}
```

Normally it would look like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: LoginPage(),
        routes: {
          Routes.loginPage: (context) => LoginPage(),
          Routes.mainPage: (context) => MainPage(),
        },
      );
  }
}
```

But I want to wrap the `LoginPage()` and `MainPage()` in the `CustomPageRouteBuilder`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody how may stuck in this later..
with this solution you could use named route with custom page builder

You can use generateRoute instead regular routes

First add your config file in MaterialApp

```
onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
```

your config generateRoute method will be something like this

```
    class Routes {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final arguments = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
     
      case StaticCategoryPage.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const StaticCategoryPage());
      case StorePage.routeName:
        return StorePageRoute(child: const StorePage());
}
```

Where StorePageRoute is your custom page route builder.

Answer (score -1):

Use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) it has a very simple route navigation like this :

```
Get.toNamed(YOUR_NAMED_ROUTE),
```

Comment: And how does this help me to use that page route builder method that I created?